# mvn archetype:generate does not work-no plugin found for prefix 'archetype'

Tags: maven-2

I want to build a simple project using a existing archetype. But I can't run `mvn archetype:generate` as it keeps telling me the following information

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the
 plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\ccen\.m2\repository), central (ht
tp://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I was using MS Windows and didn't use any `settings.xml` in my ~/.m2 folder and all stuff is brand new. Could any one help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The other thing that could be going wrong is that your machine is behind a firewall or proxy so your box is not able to hit `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`. Try accessing this URL directly in a browser or something to test if you are able to make the request.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have gone through it. I need to configure a mirror of the central repository within my company. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear to figured out the issue. My company uses Nexus (http://nexus.sonatype.org/) as a local mirror of Maven Central. Nexus is able to be configured to download any artifacts it doesn't have so that it will have it next time which is very handy so you don't have to download everything at once.

Comment: @JesseWebb I am able to access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2,
but still getting the same error.
Is it the firewall that is causing the problem? I did change the setting.xml file but still no good

Comment: I am able to access repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2 but am not able to access repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and the later is specified in error message. how to go about this issue?

Comment: how will I tackle proxy issues?

Comment: if i am able to access the url through browser what would be the issue

Answer (score 18):

The command you should be using to generate a project with an archetype is...

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

The command you posted in your question was wrong (missing the first 'e' in archetype). I assume this is just a typo in SO though because the error you posted had archetype spelled correctly.

I believe this error will occur if you are trying to execute this command from a directory that already has a `pom.xml` file in it. It will try to find an archetype plugin configuration inside the existing `pom.xml` file.

Try the command again in an empty directory, or at least in one that doesn't have a `pom.xml` file and it should work.

Comment: Hi Gweebz, yes it was a typo, I used mvn archetype:generate, and it was in a empty directory without any pom.xml, is it possible that I cannot access the repo1.maven.org/maven2 ?

Comment: Typo too... although I thought you must be kidding because if you misspell a flag (param) for any program it should give you "program unknown". It seems maven has archtype and archEtype flags?

Answer (score 11):

In case you are behind coporate firewall , configure the proxy setting using  "settings.xml" under /conf directory 
username,password,host&port values need to be provided.

```
 |
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password>
  <host>proxy.host.net</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the issue with your firewall. To check if firewall is on:

Click Start-> click Run-> type wscui.cpl -> click OK.
In Windows Security Center-> click Security
If net work Network Firewall is "on" you need to set the proxy for maven.

Go to /conf -> open settings.xml with notepad
uncomment proxy (if you don't remember proxy settings u can check in webbrowser u r using)

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <host>www-proxy.us.oracle.com</host>
        <port>80</port>
        <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

You can leave the username and pwd fields blank and set only host and port.

Comment: host and port can be found in browser's network settings (LAN settings)

Answer (score 2):

Another problem with Windows (Vista ,Windows 7 onward) is that the command prompt should be running under Administrative privileges (Right click command prompt shortcut and choose "Run ad Administrator" if UAC is on), so simply run command prompt as Administrator before executing mvn archetype:generate.

I had faced this issue while creating vaadin 7 project under windows 7 using following command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.8 -DgroupId=im.sma.testproject -DartifactId=testproject -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=war
```

- SMA

Answer (score 2):

I was banging with this problem 2 days, I checked proxy , copied settings.xml from conf folder , deleted user local .m2 folder , came out of eclipse and installed maven directly and tried . None of the above worked.

Finallay the problem fixed by upgrading java home form 1.7 to 1.8 . My maven version is **Apache Maven 3.6.3** .

Maven should report proper error for the specific issue but it is not.

Up voted the suggestion of java upgrade in this thread , previously they were down voted

Answer (score 1):

- To add **Venerik's** answer I would elaborate a bit for the naive users like me;

proxy settings in maven
go to apache-maven-3.3.9\conf folder and find settings.xml
open it in any text editor
go to the block of code that looks like below

```
 <proxies>
<!-- proxy
 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
 |
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password>
  <host>proxy.host.net</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
-->
 </proxies>
```

- Now uncomment the code from (proxy.../proxy) by cutting it and
  pasting it

just after (proxies).

Now change according to your proxy settings
In my case it looks like the following

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>      
      <host>authproxy.serc.iisc.ernet.in</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
  <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the      network.
 |
   -->
  </proxies>
```

Now try running **mvn archetype:generate** and it should run and download

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was just run mvn archtype:generate in Safe Mode under your user profile. After that I could run it in normal boot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem disabling the antivirus for a few time while the project is create .

[image: Click here how to do that with avast]

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue with maven 3. I just upgraded from jdk7 to jdk8 and the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem when using maven 3.6.1 with jdk 1.7.40.

To solve this, i simply update my version of JDk to 1.8.241.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and the thing that worked for me was reinstalling java

1. `sudo yum install java`
2. Find the path where java is installed, you can use `which java` or `whereis java` or `sudo find / -name javac`

   For me, it was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin`
3. `sudo vi ~/.bashrc`
4. add below lines

   `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin`
5. source `.bashrc`

and then try your command - `mvn archetype:generate`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache Maven repository URL is updated from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ in NetBeans 8.2 or lower version we are facing this issue.

So what's the solution?

**Solution 1:-**
User Terminal to download an updated maven dependencies Check out this Guide on [Maven.Apache.Org](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

**Solution 2:-**
Update your NetBeans, Move to [Apache NetBeans 11](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

If this warning is accompanied by the warning:

```
Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

Then check your java version. I was able to solve this issue by upgrading my java version from 7 to 10. See the following:

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2364

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem. Root cause: typed mvn generate:archetype instead archetype:generate.
mvn archetype:generate - is correct way.

Comment: This is not an answer.