# Error Creating a new project In maven 3 in linux

Tags: maven, maven-3

whene i trying to create a new project in maven via  mvn archetype:generate
i gotta this probleme :

No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories

i have  a mvn version 3.0.5
  jdk version 1.6.
  system linux

please if someone can solve this probleme , thanks in advance :)

Comment: please see this http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472782/mvn-archetypegenerate-does-not-work-no-plugin-found-for-prefox-archetype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your machine is behind a firewall or proxy so your machine is not able to hit any HTTP request. Turn off your firewall and then try to access this or Create your project

Comment: OOOOOK thanks for your response i will try to entr url
but its it works good
i have already seen the same topic like my problem but doasnt work :(
thnkx for all :)

Comment: You Welcome.Please Accept the answer if it help you out