# Maven: No Plugin Found For Prefix "Archetype"

Tags: maven, compiler-errors, archetypes

currently I am trying to create maven project for activiti workflow engine. However, when I use command "mvn archetype: generate", it always show following error:
[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

What is wrong with my maven?

NB: I have read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472782/mvn-archetypegenerate-does-not-work-no-plugin-found-for-prefox-archetype), but I can still access following link: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins and also I have checked that archetype plugin is there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you typed the command exactly as given ? `mvn archetype: generate` there is a space which shouldn't be there `mvn archetype:generate` ? BTW: Which Maven version do you use? Can you post the output before the are with `BUILD FAILURE...`?

Comment: Yes I have tried it and it generate the same error. I have update the picture too. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be unable to get a connection to central. Are you behind a proxy? Have your configured maven to use that proxy?

Comment: yes I am. How can I configure it? Thanks

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Try this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472782/mvn-archetypegenerate-does-not-work-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-archetype