# eclipse maven No plugin found for prefix 'maven-assembly-plugin'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, raspberry-pi, m2eclipse

I am trying to use maven in the Eclipse Luna environment to assemble an executable jar and the deploy it to a Raspberry Pi, I found what looks like an appropriate Maven script, but Maven does not appear to be finding its first plugin and declares a build failure see console log below:-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 21.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 32.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.404 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-21T20:01:39+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/164M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'maven-assembly-plugin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\GJWood\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>RPITank</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- DEFAULT RASPBERRY PI PROPERTIES -->
    <pi.host>192.168.1.123</pi.host>
    <pi.port>22</pi.port>
    <pi.user>pi</pi.user>
    <pi.password>raspberry</pi.password>
    <pi.deployDirectory>/home/pi/artifacts</pi.deployDirectory>
    <pi.main.class>RPITank</pi.main.class>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- This plugin will generate JAR MANIFEST file inside the JAR in order to make our application easily runnable -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${pi.main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!--This plugin will Transfer the executable JAR file to the Pi and runs it -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <!-- ensure the target directory exists on the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}" password="${pi.password}" 
                                     trust="true" failonerror="false" verbose="true" 
                                     command="mkdir --parents ${pi.deployDirectory}"/>

                            <!-- copy the JAR file to the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <scp
                                file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
                                todir="${pi.user}:${pi.password}@${pi.host}:${pi.deployDirectory}"
                                port="${pi.port}" trust="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                            </scp> 

                            <!-- run the JAR file on the Raspberry Pi -->
                            <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}"
                                     password="${pi.password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                                     verbose="true" 
                                     command="java -jar ${pi.deployDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have installed Maven on Eclipse and I have checked that the plugin files are on my PC and that the Classpath is set (and this is were the files are)

```
C:\Users\GJWood\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-assembly-plugin\2.2-beta-5
```

I have also tried referencing the jar files in Referenced Libraries

All to no avail!

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472782/mvn-archetypegenerate-does-not-work-no-plugin-found-for-prefix-archetype

Comment: How have you called Maven?

Comment: Accessing frome home so no proxy issues.

Comment: Maven called via run rightclick m2 option in eclipse

Comment: To be clear I am running M2Eclipse from within Eclipse rather than command line maven

Answer (score 0):

The original objective of my question was to deploy code from eclipse to a Raspberry Pi, I have now achieved this for a simple "hello world" program as follows:

1. Probably unnecessary but I thought I would start from a clean install of the latest version of Eclipse (Neon)
2. Updated pom.xml to the one shown below

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0
       org.ladbury
       HelloWorld
       0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       HelloWorld
       Simple

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

       <!-- DEFAULT RASPBERRY PI PROPERTIES -->
       <pi.host>192.168.1.123</pi.host>
       <pi.port>22</pi.port>
       <pi.user>pi</pi.user>
       <pi.password>raspberry</pi.password>
       <pi.deployDirectory>/home/pi/artifacts</pi.deployDirectory>
       <pi.main.class>org.ladbury.testPkg.HelloWorld</pi.main.class>
   </properties>

   <build>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.5.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                           <mainClass>${pi.main.class}</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <!--This plugin will transfer the executable JAR file to the Pi and runs 
               it -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.8</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>ant-copy-execute</id>
                       <phase>install</phase>
                       <configuration>

                           <target>
                               <!-- ensure the target directory exists on the Raspberry Pi -->
                               <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}"
                                   password="${pi.password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                                   verbose="true" command="mkdir --parents ${pi.deployDirectory}" />

                               <!-- copy the JAR file to the Raspberry Pi -->
                               <scp file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                                   todir="${pi.user}:${pi.password}@${pi.host}:${pi.deployDirectory}"
                                   port="${pi.port}" trust="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true" />


                               <!-- run the JAR file on the Raspberry Pi -->
                               <sshexec host="${pi.host}" port="${pi.port}" username="${pi.user}"
                                   password="${pi.password}" trust="true" failonerror="false"
                                   verbose="true"
                                   command="java -jar ${pi.deployDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                           </target>

                       </configuration>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>run</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                       <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                       <version>1.9.6</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

   - To execute there are two steps

3.1 Build a jar file containing the main class:

- Right click project in the package explorer
- Select Run As then Run Configurations
- In the maven section, main tab, fill in the goals box with jar:jar
- in the name box put Hello World Jar
- click the run button, this should build the jar as shown below

  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [INFO]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Building HelloWorld 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
  [INFO] Building jar:           C:\Users\GJWood\git\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\target\HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 1.104 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-29T16:13:48+01:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/170M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

3.2 Transfer the jar via SSH and execute it on the Raspberry PI as follows
 - Right click project in the package explorer
 - Select Run As then Run Configurations
 - In the maven section, main tab, fill in the goals box with antrun:run@ant-copy-execute
 - in the name box put HelloWorld AntRun
 - click the run button, this should transfer the program and run it as shown below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloWorld 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (ant-copy-execute) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
  [sshexec] Connecting to 192.168.1.123:22
  [sshexec] Connecting to 192.168.1.123 port 22
  [sshexec] Connection established
  [sshexec] Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u2
  [sshexec] Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.50
  [sshexec] CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
  [sshexec] aes256-ctr is not available.
  [sshexec] aes192-ctr is not available.
  [sshexec] aes256-cbc is not available.
  [sshexec] aes192-cbc is not available.
  [sshexec] arcfour256 is not available.
  [sshexec] CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
  [sshexec] kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
  [sshexec] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: 
  [sshexec] kex: server: 
  [sshexec] kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
  [sshexec] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
  [sshexec] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
  [sshexec] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  [sshexec] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  [sshexec] kex: client: none
  [sshexec] kex: client: none
  [sshexec] kex: client: 
  [sshexec] kex: client: 
  [sshexec] kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  [sshexec] kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
  [sshexec] expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
  [sshexec] ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
  [sshexec] Permanently added '192.168.1.123' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: publickey
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: password
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: password
  [sshexec] Authentication succeeded (password).
  [sshexec] cmd : mkdir --parents /home/pi/artifacts
  [sshexec] Disconnecting from 192.168.1.123 port 22
  [sshexec] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
      [scp] Connecting to 192.168.1.123:22
      [scp] Connecting to 192.168.1.123 port 22
      [scp] Connection established
      [scp] Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u2
      [scp] Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.50
      [scp] CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
      [scp] aes256-ctr is not available.
      [scp] aes192-ctr is not available.
      [scp] aes256-cbc is not available.
      [scp] aes192-cbc is not available.
      [scp] arcfour256 is not available.
      [scp] CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
      [scp] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
      [scp] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
      [scp] kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
      [scp] kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
      [scp] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
      [scp] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
      [scp] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
      [scp] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
      [scp] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
      [scp] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
      [scp] kex: server: 
      [scp] kex: server: 
      [scp] kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
      [scp] kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
      [scp] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
      [scp] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
      [scp] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
      [scp] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
      [scp] kex: client: none
      [scp] kex: client: none
      [scp] kex: client: 
      [scp] kex: client: 
      [scp] kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
      [scp] kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
      [scp] SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
      [scp] expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
      [scp] ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
      [scp] Permanently added '192.168.1.123' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
      [scp] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
      [scp] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
      [scp] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
      [scp] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
      [scp] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
      [scp] Next authentication method: publickey
      [scp] Authentications that can continue: password
      [scp] Next authentication method: password
      [scp] Authentication succeeded (password).
      [scp] Sending: HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar : 3278
      [scp] File transfer time: 0.01 Average Rate: 409,750.0 B/s
      [scp] done.
      [scp] Disconnecting from 192.168.1.123 port 22
      [scp] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
  [sshexec] Connecting to 192.168.1.123:22
  [sshexec] Connecting to 192.168.1.123 port 22
  [sshexec] Connection established
  [sshexec] Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u2
  [sshexec] Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.50
  [sshexec] CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
  [sshexec] aes256-ctr is not available.
  [sshexec] aes192-ctr is not available.
  [sshexec] aes256-cbc is not available.
  [sshexec] aes192-cbc is not available.
  [sshexec] arcfour256 is not available.
  [sshexec] CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
  [sshexec] kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
  [sshexec] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
  [sshexec] kex: server: 
  [sshexec] kex: server: 
  [sshexec] kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
  [sshexec] kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
  [sshexec] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
  [sshexec] kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
  [sshexec] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  [sshexec] kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  [sshexec] kex: client: none
  [sshexec] kex: client: none
  [sshexec] kex: client: 
  [sshexec] kex: client: 
  [sshexec] kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  [sshexec] kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
  [sshexec] expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
  [sshexec] ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
  [sshexec] Permanently added '192.168.1.123' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: publickey
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: password
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: password
  [sshexec] Authentication succeeded (password).
  [sshexec] cmd : java -jar /home/pi/artifacts/HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Hello World
  [sshexec] Disconnecting from 192.168.1.123 port 22
  [sshexec] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.052 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-29T15:11:30+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```